# Azure Storage Lifecycle management filter containers

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have the following container's structure in my storage:

```
    container-1
     + folder 1
     + folder 2
   
    container-2
      + folder 3
      + folder 4

   public-container
     + f5
     + 6

   another-container
     + f7
```

And I want to define a rule which will move blobs to cool storage only in containers that start with **"container-"**

 Can I define the following filter set and will it affect only blobs in containers starting with **container-**?[image]

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: @tommylux not sure, I wrote custom Azure Function which performs what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

Recently, there is an update for life cycle management, we can now use `container-` as prefix to filter containers(like container-1, container-sss etc.).

---

<strike>No, the prefix match must start with a full container name.</strike>

So in your case, you must define 2 prefix match, like `container-1` and `container-2`.

Comment: Confirmed. ‘container-‘ will find container-1 etc. tested recently.